# Master "SIM card question"?

Tags: discussion

We have a ton of questions regarding SIM cards, how to buy and activate one upon arrival in a new country, etc.

About half of the new ones get marked as duplicate, and the other half are nearly duplicates, except they ask about a new region.

Would it be wise to create a master "SIM Card" question, with links to all the others?  I envision something such as:

---

### Europe

#### United Kingdom

- [What are prepaid SIM card options for data in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/9328/444)
- [Buying a SIM card at Heathrow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3758/444)

#### France

- [Can I buy a prepaid mobile data plan while on route in France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8642/444)

etc, etc

As new non-duplicate questions are asked, they can be added to the accepted Comunity-Wiki answer.

Is this a good idea?  Would it serve better than the existing search function (MHO, yes, it would--else I wouldn't make this suggestion).

Answer (score 3):

I'd rather mark questions aggressively as duplicate (and encourage people to find duplicates and flag them as so) whenever a new one is asked. A single question with separate countries would be too unwieldy (there are more than 180 countries).

Comment: Perhaps additionally tagging these questions consistently would help?  (I notice the 'simcards' tag has only 2 questions, and 'cellphones' is perhaps too brad?)

Comment: @Flimzy Good point about the simcards tag, might need a retagging effort.

Comment: It looks like the 'simcards' tag is a synonym to 'cellphones', but due to a probable bug, it shows up separately in the list of tags, with a 'x 2'.  I might propose un-aliasing it, or coming up with a new tag for sim-card questions...

Answer (score 2):

I totally support the idea, a wiki with links to different questions will make it simpler even if we want to mark new questions as duplicate. If you ever start making such a post I will help you in adding the links.

For those who think this idea is bad, SO has some nice [community wikis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) full with links to serve similar purposes.

Comment: That wiki exists: it's the [tag:cellphones] tag wiki.

Comment: That SO question is not a good example to take since community wikis are discouraged now, as pointed out in the comments for that question too. We have one too ([bike rentals in Europe](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/250/which-european-cities-have-bike-rental-stations-for-tourists)) but it's considered a legacy question here too.